# How to mask/force case of First Name and Last Name letters only

Tags: c#, string, input, error-handling

I want to prompt user to give his/her `name`. but his `name` should only contain *letters* and having *no numbers*. It also allows to have a *space* in between his first and middle name like `"Walter junior"`.
I know how to loop through the input with `char.IsLetter` and I also know how to check the input by `using == null`; but the *space* in between *is a problem*.

Comment: How is it a problem?  What have you tried and what isn't working?  This is probably also a good time to start looking into regular expressions (using the `Regex` class) to test strings against patterns instead of looping through each character.

Comment: but there is no pattern. my name differs from yours! I dont know if the users input has 1, 2 or 3 parts and I dont know which language he is gonna use. I thought regular expression is just for fixed things like phone number which only comes in 1 format.

Comment: The "pattern" is whatever you define it to be.  Whatever logic you are trying to implement to decide whether someone's name is valid or not.  (Side note: You shouldn't do this at all.  A person's name is whatever they say it is.  Read this: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names)

Comment: fair enough but I still want to define some limitations. My limitations are: just English characters, spaces in between are allowed, no numbers, no punctuation marks and, of course, no null. Could you please write a piece of code with regular expression defining these?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string name = ... 

  bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^\w+(?: \w+)*$");
```

If letters are *English ones* (i.e. `A..Z a..z`) only:

```
  bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*$");
```

With a help of *regular expressions* you can implement a more elaborated validation, e.g.

1. Each name part must start from capital letter
2. Each name part can contain small letters
3. Name can have up to 3 parts separted by spaces

Pattern:

```
  bool isValid = Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*(?: \p{Lu}\p{Ll}*){0,2}$");
```

Comment: correct me please if I am mistaken. @ is for the syntax itself, [A-Za-z] are allowed characters for the first part. what is "^"? what is "?:" ? what is "+"?  and what is "*$" ? oh! there are many things I dont know

Comment: Very awesome of you to do this, OP should actually go RegEx.

Comment: well `^` and `$` are *anchors*, begin and end of the strings, so `^...$` means that the *entire string* should match the pattern. `+` and `*` and `{0, 2}` are *quantifiers* mean "1 or more timrs", "0 or more times" and "from 0 up to 2 times". `(?: )` is a *grouping* where `?:` means "don't count it in Groups[...]"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference